# How do I fade in/out an object in Blender 2.8 Eevee?

Tags: animation, transparency, eevee-render-engine

I'm kinda new to using Blender Eevee. I used to use Cycles, but that took too long to render. I'm doing a text animation with a video in the background, and I want the text to fade in and fade out. However, I cannot do this because Eevee is different from Cycles. Is there any way I can animate the transparency of an object so I can fade it in and out?

Answer (score 9):

[image: final]

Of course it is. The only "catch" is to change **Blend Mode** under **Material > Settings** tab to **Alpha Blend** and turn off **Show Backface**.

Then regularly you can animate **Factor** between your shader and **Transparent** shader (full white colour).

[image: node setup]

Answer (score 2):

Looked for a solution to this question
**Q: Image bleed when using Import Image as Plane [duplicate]**
which is linked here.

My proposal:
[image: Image as plane w/math-node]

I put a math node between image and Mix Shader, set it to multiply. Wit the second value set to 0 the image is not visible. Obviously when I set the second value to one it is fully visible.